# Plotly-Dash: How to update DatePickerRange dynamically from dropdown

Tags: callback, datepicker, plotly-dash

Does anybody have ideas on how to change DatePickerRange start_date (X) & end_date (Y) by selecting the time-frame with a Dropdown (with options like Today, Yesterday, Last 7 days, Last 4 weeks, etc)? I guess this should be doable with Callbacks. Thx.

---

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from datetime import date as dt, timedelta
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])


date_today = dt.today()
date_yesterday = dt.today() - timedelta(days=1)
date_6_days_ago = dt.today() - timedelta(days=6)

today_list=[
            {'label': 'Start date', 'value': date_today},
            {'label': 'End date', 'value': date_today}]  


yesterday_list=[
            {'label': 'Start date', 'value': date_yesterday},
            {'label': 'End date', 'value': date_yesterday}]  

last_7_days_list =[
            {'label': 'Start date', 'value': date_6_days_ago},
            {'label': 'End date', 'value': date_today}] 


timeframe_list=[
            {'label': 'Today', 'value': today_list},
            {'label': 'Yesterday', 'value': yesterday_list},
            {'label': 'Last 7 days', 'value': last_7_days_list}]

datepicker_selector = dcc.DatePickerRange(
    id='datepicker',
    display_format='DD-MM-YYYY',
    first_day_of_week=1,
    start_date = X,
    end_date = Y,
    max_date_allowed=date_today)

dropdown_selector = dcc.Dropdown (id = 'timeframe_dropdown', multi=False, options=timeframe_list,value=today_list),


app.layout = html.Div([html.Div([
    html.Div(dropdown_selector),
    html.Div(datepicker_selector)
    ])])
server = app.server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed possible using a callback function.

To my knowledge it is not possible to store multiple values for each label in a dropdown. So the way i've done it is to just make the values in the dropdown the same as the labels. Then in the callback function return the corresponding start and end dates depending on the selected value in the dropdown.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from datetime import date as dt, timedelta
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id = 'timeframe_dropdown', 
        multi = False, 
        options = [
            {'label': 'Today', 'value': 'Today'},
            {'label': 'Yesterday', 'value': 'Yesterday'},
            {'label': 'Last 7 days', 'value': 'Last 7 days'}
        ], 
        value='Today',
        clearable=False,
    ),
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='datepicker',
        display_format='DD-MM-YYYY',
        first_day_of_week=1,
        max_date_allowed=dt.today(),
    ),
])

@app.callback(
    [Output('datepicker', 'start_date'), # This updates the field start_date in the DatePicker
    Output('datepicker', 'end_date')], # This updates the field end_date in the DatePicker
    [Input('timeframe_dropdown', 'value')],
)
def updateDataPicker(dropdown_value):
    if dropdown_value == 'Today':
        return dt.today(), dt.today()
    elif dropdown_value == 'Yesterday':
        return dt.today() - timedelta(1), dt.today() - timedelta(1)
    else:
        return dt.today() - timedelta(6), dt.today()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0")
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, your solution is the perfect one. Thx a lot.

Comment: @xcdata If the suggestion works, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Kristian Haga How about if you want to add a 'custom' label and then the whole calendar comes up with start date and end date. Is that doable as well?

Comment: @ssmm Could you elaborate a bit? I'm not sure i quite understood your question

Comment: @KristianHaga currently, there's 3 options in the dropdown: 'today', 'yesterday', 'last 7 days'. What if i want to add another that says 'custom' and i want it to show the calendar so i can choose whatever dates i want, is that possible?

Comment: @ssmm Yes that is possible. The DatePickerRange component is by default 'custom', where you can click the dates you want. So you don't really need the dropdown menu if that is not essential for your application.

Comment: @KristianHaga what if i want the options 'today', 'yesterday' and 'last 7 days' in the to remain in options? But I also want to add 'custom' in the dropdown menu so that the end users can choose the dates that they want.

Comment: @ssmm Then you would add 'custom' to the dropdown menu, and in the callback function you would add an if statement that says to return None and None if the dropdown_value is equal to 'custom'. The datepicker will then be empty and you can choose the dates you want. You may also want to change the minimum and maximum dates allowed when initializing the DatePickerRange component.

Comment: @KristianHaga got it. I was able to add 'custom' to the dropdown menu. Thank you!

Comment: @KristianHaga Sorry, I was wrong I didn't make it work. I was just able to add 'custom' in the drop down value but the dates on the calendar don't change when I choose other options. By default, it just stayed in the date today. what should i put in the value of 'custom' in the dropdown options?

Comment: @KristianHaga  also, here's how my callback function look like:

def updateDataPicker(dropdown_value):
    if dropdown_value == 'Today':
        return dt.today(), dt.today()
    elif dropdown_value == 'Yesterday':
        return dt.today() - timedelta(1), dt.today() - timedelta(1)
    elif dropdown_value == 'Last 7 days':
        return dt.today() - timedelta(6), dt.today()
    elif dropdown_value == 'Custom':
        return None
    else:
        return dt.today() - timedelta(6), dt.today()

Comment: @KristianHaga I posted a new question for it. You may find the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590162/dash-dynamic-dropdown-with-custom-option. Thank you!