# Dash Dynamic Dropdown with Custom Option

Tags: python, date, calendar, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu that says 'today', 'yesterday', 'last 7 days' and 'custom'. I want the calendar to automatically update when I choose an option in the dropdown menu. For 'custom' I want to pull the calendar so I can choose any dates I want. Here's the sample code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from datetime import date as dt, timedelta
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id = 'timeframe_dropdown', 
        multi = False, 
        options = [
            {'label': 'Today', 'value': 'Today'},
            {'label': 'Yesterday', 'value': 'Yesterday'},
            {'label': 'Last 7 days', 'value': 'Last 7 days'},
            {'label': 'Custom', 'value': 'None'}
        ], 
        value='Today',
        clearable=False,
    ),
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='datepicker',
        display_format='DD-MM-YYYY',
        first_day_of_week=1,
        min_date_allowed=dt(2019, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=dt(2021, 2, 28),
    ),
])

@app.callback(
    [Output('datepicker', 'start_date'), # This updates the field start_date in the DatePicker
    Output('datepicker', 'end_date')], # This updates the field end_date in the DatePicker
    [Input('timeframe_dropdown', 'value')],
)
def updateDataPicker(dropdown_value):
    if dropdown_value == 'Today':
        return dt.today(), dt.today()
    elif dropdown_value == 'Yesterday':
        return dt.today() - timedelta(1), dt.today() - timedelta(1)
    elif dropdown_value == 'Last 7 days':
        return dt.today() - timedelta(6), dt.today()
    elif dropdown_value == 'Custom':
        return None
    else:
        return dt.today() - timedelta(6), dt.today()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0")
```

The dropdown and calendar show up on that code, however, they are not linked together. The dates in the calendar don't change when I choose other options, it just stays in the date today by default.

Comment: I ran your code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @coralvanda on my end, the calendar only updates when I choose 'today'. However, it doesn't change, when I choose the other options like 'yesterday', 'last 7 days' and 'custom'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, just two small mistakes.

In your dropdown you are adding a new option to your dropdown `{'label': 'Custom', 'value': 'None'}`. However you are setting its value to `None`. The dropdown value are the ones we receive in the callback function as input `[Input('timeframe_dropdown', 'value')]`. So in your if-statement you are checking `elif dropdown_value == 'Custom':`. This will never be the case, as you set the Custom label to have value `None`.

Another little mistake is that we are declaring two `Output` values in the callback, both `start_date` and  `end_date`, so we need to always return two values. `elif dropdown_value == 'Custom': return None` should instead be `elif dropdown_value == 'Custom': return None, None`.

Full code with fixes:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from datetime import date as dt, timedelta
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id = 'timeframe_dropdown', 
        multi = False, 
        options = [
            {'label': 'Today', 'value': 'Today'},
            {'label': 'Yesterday', 'value': 'Yesterday'},
            {'label': 'Last 7 days', 'value': 'Last 7 days'},
            {'label': 'Custom', 'value': 'Custom'}
        ], 
        value='Today',
        clearable=False,
    ),
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='datepicker',
        display_format='DD-MM-YYYY',
        first_day_of_week=1,
        min_date_allowed=dt(2019, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=dt(2021, 2, 28),
    ),
])

@app.callback(
    [Output('datepicker', 'start_date'), # This updates the field start_date in the DatePicker
    Output('datepicker', 'end_date')], # This updates the field end_date in the DatePicker
    [Input('timeframe_dropdown', 'value')],
)
def updateDataPicker(dropdown_value):
    if dropdown_value == 'Today':
        return dt.today(), dt.today()
    elif dropdown_value == 'Yesterday':
        return dt.today() - timedelta(1), dt.today() - timedelta(1)
    elif dropdown_value == 'Last 7 days':
        return dt.today() - timedelta(6), dt.today()
    elif dropdown_value == 'Custom':
        return None, None
    else:
        return dt.today() - timedelta(6), dt.today()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: the calendar only automatically updates when I choose 'Today' and 'Custom', it stays on the date today for 'Yesterday' and 'Last 7 days'

Comment: That is not the case on my computer. Are you running the code in my answer?

Comment: yes, I updated my code and apply the changes you have made. I wonder why

Comment: I have other stuff in my code, that might have affected it? Cos when I tried running just that code, it's working.

Comment: That is possible. Hard for me to say without looking at your code.

Comment: This might be overkill, but can you also look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66571058/dash-filter-df-based-on-dates. I am trying to create a df without the dates in the column but which dates can be manipulated thru the calendar. This is the other stuff in my code, btw :)

Comment: i figured out why it doesn't work on my end, I haven't imported timedelta in my env. When I did, it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!